# Struts2 i18n java properties, how to show special character?

Tags: internationalization, struts2

If any body else have solution on this please replay.

I'm using Struts2 and `getText` method to fill i18n and text tags.

For example I use:

```
free.text.search.label=&#269eské On-line Hledat
```

`&#269` is a HTML code for special character `č` (Czech Republic). I want to use in properties file.

But in my JSP, I get : `&#269eské On-line Hledat` instead of `české On-line Hledat`

I use this to display text on my JSP:

```
<s:label for="searchInput" value="%{getText('free.text.search.label')}" />
```

So what's the error? Actually this problem i am facing for label as well for button.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\u010D` instead of `&#269`

**.properties**

```
free.text.search.label=\u010Deské On-line Hledat
```

**.jsp**

```
<s:label key="free.text.search.label" />
```

**Output**

```
české On-line Hledat
```

---

**How I solved it?**

Just paste `české On-line Hledat` into `.properties` file in my IDE (**Eclipse**).

**Or**

> **See**
>
> **[Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CARON'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10d/index.htm)**
>   **(Encodings > C/C++/Java source code)**
>
> **[A to Z Index of Unicode Characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a.htm)**
>   **[Unicode Character Search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm)**

Answer (score 2):

Well i am not able to understand your issue properly
but few points i would like to mention here

```
<s:label for="searchInput" value="%{getText('free.text.search.label')}" />
```

use key in place of this to make this more easy to read and maintain
like

```
<s:label for="searchInput" key="free.text.search.label" />
```

also since meta tags are no longer applicable to struts2 so you can try using this

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

May be this will help you to display special characters correctly